# RX - rethrow an error in containing method

Tags: c#, .net, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I need to translate an error in an RX stream (`IObservable`) into an exception in the method that contains the subscription to the stream

(because of this issue https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/pull/1331 , Whereby errors arent serialised to clients.) Once this issue is fixed I will revert to handling error properly

e.g.

I have the following method

```
public IObservable<StreamItem> LiveStream()
{
    _mySvc.Start();
    return _mySvc.ThingChanged();
}
```

So I have tried to subscribe to the stream and rethrow the error, but it still doesnt get transmitted to the client:

```
public IObservable<StreamItem> LiveStream()
{
    _mySvc.Start();
    _mySvc.ThingChanged().Subscribe(item => {}, OnError, () => {});
    return _mySvc.ThingChanged();
}

private void OnError(Exception exception)
{
    throw new Exception(exception.Message);
}
```

What I need is the equivelent of throwing in the LiveStream method

e.g. this error is propogated to the client

```
public IObservable<StreamItem> LiveStream()
{
    _mySvc.Start();
    throw new Exception("some error message");
    return _mySvc.ThingChanged();
}
```

any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I have found this as well, especially with a "contained" reactive pipeline—that is, one with a well-defined beginning and end. In situations like those, it may suffice to simply allow underlying exceptions to bubble up to the containing scope. But as you have found, that concept is rather foreign to Rx generally: what happens in the pipeline stays in the pipeline.

The only way out of this that I have found in a contained scenario is to "slip" the error out of the stream using `Catch()`, and hand back an empty `IObservable` to allow the stream to halt naturally (otherwise, you'll hang if you're `await`ing an `IObservable` for completion).

This will not work *within* your `LiveStream()` method, because that context/scope should have passed out of existence long before you're consuming your stream. So, this will have to happen in the context that contains the whole pipeline.

```
Exception error = null;
var source = LiveStream()
  .Catch<WhatYoureStreaming, Exception>(ex => {error = ex; return Observable.Empty<WhatYoureStreaming>(); })
  ...

await source; // if this is how you're awaiting completion

// not a real exception type, use your own
if (error != null) throw new ContainingException("oops", error);
```

Just don't `throw error` there at the end, you'll lose the original stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public IObservable<StreamItem> LiveStream()
{
    _mySvc.Start();
    return
        _mySvc
            .ThingChanged()
            .Materialize()
            .Do(x =>
            {
                if (x.Kind == NotificationKind.OnError)
                {
                    OnError(x.Exception);
                }
            })
            .Dematerialize();
}
```

I'm not sure that this is the best way to go - throwing exceptions like this can cause you grief inside a stream where you end up with the wrong exception handlers firing. You might need to find another solution.

Comment: thanks, that doesn't propagate the error to the client unfortunately.

Comment: @ChrisCa - What's happening to the error? Can you create a simple sample that shows that it doesn't work?

Comment: sure. if you download this sample https://github.com/radu-matei/signalr-samples/tree/master/streaming/web and replace the hub with the contents of this gist https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c7eb9a80a5740a24aa34f1091abce329 you will see that the error never gets caught in the try catch block. let me know if you need any more info

Comment: also, that sample has a small error in the index.html - in the subscription the method should be called error, not err e.g.
error: function(err){console.log(err); }, @Enigmativity

Comment: @ChrisCa - Oh, I see. The exception won't get caught by an external `try`/`catch` in the code that created the observable. You need to move the exception handling to within the definition of the observable using either a `.Create` or `.Defer` operator to encapsulate it. I'll try to edit my answer later when I have more time.

Comment: yeah, the issue is that because of that SignalR issue I mentioned in the original question, errors in the stream are not correctly sent to the client. So I'm trying to recognise when there is an error in the stream and manually throw an  exception. So I'm not trying to handle the error in that method, I just put a try catch there to demonstrate that the error doesnt get caught. and so I cant manually throw it. So looking for a way to know when there is an error in the stream so I can manually communicate something to the client - thanks @Enigmativity

Comment: @ChrisCa - Having looked at it a second time I'm not sure why my answer isn't correctly firing `OnError(x.Exception)`. Can you debug to see if it is or not? Maybe it's a threading issue?

Comment: OnError(x.Exception) **does** get fired. however, when that method then manually throws the exception, it keeps the exception inside the stream (sorry if that's not the correct terminology, I'm an RX newbie). And so that isnt correctly communicated to the javascript client. I need something the equivalent of manually throwing an exception in the containing method. Or just someway to know an error has happened in the stream (and get the exception message), so I can manually communicate what's gone wrong to the browser

Comment: @ChrisCa - It sounds like you need to marshal the call back to the thread that created the SignalR object.

Comment: yeah - is there a good way to do that? btw, the code I linked to above should run, if you need to see what I mean

Comment: @ChrisCa - Do you know how `SynchronizationContext` works?

Comment: not in any great deal, but can look into it. any pointers to something specific? btw, the Hub class is an asp.net thing and so newed up by the framework, i don't have much control on how that is created, that I'm aware of anyway

Comment: @ChrisCa - You'll need to check with an asp.net guru on how to marshal to that thread - if it's possible.

Comment: ok cheers - I was under the impression that RX runs on the same thread as it is created on, is that not the case?

Comment: @ChrisCa - There are a few operators that do, but most do not. It's when it uses multiple threads that you get the most power out of it. Trying seeing what threads your code is using. That might help you to understand what's going on.

Comment: I'm not explicitly creating any new threads. the problem manifests itself even in the toy sample I posted above, which is cut back to virtually nothing

Comment: @ChrisCa - Rx creates them all the time. What's the "toy sample"?

Comment: it's the links mentioned in the 3rd comment of this discussion - even that has the problem