# Is it possible to re-throw an error in the calling method in RxAndroid?

Tags: java, android, rx-android, reactivex

Inspired by [.Net TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl), I'm trying to find a way to handle an error outside the RX pipe. Specifically, on error, I wish the Observer pipe to stop, and pass control back to the surrounding method. Something like:

```
public void testRxJava() {
    try {
        Observable.range(0, 5)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(i -> { throw new RuntimeException(); })
            .subscribe();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // I was hoping to get here on the main thread, but crashed instead
        Log.i("Test", "Will never get here");
    }
}
```

This will cause the application to crash with an `io.reactivex.rxjava3.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException`, which will not be caught in the `catch` clause, and will instead invoke the main thread's `uncaughtException()` handler.

Trying to throw from the error handler in `subscribe()` does not work either, again falling back to the `uncaughtException()` handler.

Is there a way to re-throw or otherwise pass the error information to the calling method?

A similar question for C# is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48581889/rx-rethrow-an-error-in-containing-method).

Comment: You can catch the error in `onResumeNext` and call the method you wish based on instance of that `Exception`. Since the error itself also will end up in `onError` callback of `subscribe` you can set it do nothing, or simply ignore that kind of error there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing. As far as I can tell, this is the only way to leave the ReactiveX pipe, and let the surrounding code handle the error. Would be happy if someone has a more elegant way:

```
public void testRxJava() {
    try {
        // will be null if no error, will hold a Throwable on error
        AtomicReference<Throwable> opError = new AtomicReference<>(null);

        Observable.range(0, 5)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(i -> { throw new RuntimeException(); }) // throws
            .blockingSubscribe(
                result -> Log.i(TAG, "will never happen"),
                error -> { opError.set(error); } // sets reference to the error without crashing the app
            );

        // re-throw
        if(opError.get() != null) {
            throw new Exception(opError.get());
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Test", "exception", ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried catching the error like so

```
    Observable.range(0, 5)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .doOnError {
            //your error caught here
        }         
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .map({ i -> throw RuntimeException() })
        .subscribe()
```

Comment: It has the same effect as throwing from `subscribe()`, which is not what I'm after. I'm looking for a way to pass control to the surrounding method.